# How do I get rid of old, orphaned network hardware ports under macOS?

Tags: macos, network, preferences

I'm frequently changing USB-C Ethernet adapters with my M1 MacBook Pro 14" because they get lost or broken.

But, although I've removed them from Network Setup under Preferences they stay under `ifconfig` and under `networksetup -listallhardwareports`.

**How Do I get rid of them?**

[image: orphaned usb-c ethernet adapters]

`ifconfig en4 destroy` or `remove` for example did not work.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide the output directly from Terminal with an [edit] instead of a screenshot?  It’s difficult to read, isn’t indexed by search engines and can’t be copy/pasted by anyone hoping to answer.  You can pipe this to your clipboard by appending `| pbcopy` to your command

Comment: Have you tried deleting the network devices in System Settings > Network? Just scroll down to "Other Services", select the device you want to delete, click the button "Delete Service..." and confirm deletion.